# React Native infinite scroll problems with few elements

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, infinite-scroll

I'm using React Native with Firebase and I'm trying to use an infinite scroll (load more) on my Listview, everything works fine if the first fetch can fill the list for the entire height of the screen because onEndReached is fired but when there are few elements and the listview is not filled at all on the screen, onEndReached is not fired and so it doesn't download and fill with next records. Anyone can help me handling this situation?
Thanks in advance.

```
return (
        <View style={{flex:1}}>  
            <ListView
                dataSource={this.state.userDataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
                style={{paddingTop: 10, paddingBottom: 10}}
                enableEmptySections={true}
                renderFooter={this.renderFooter.bind(this)}
                onEndReached={this.infScrollFetch.bind(this)}
                onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
                refreshControl={
                    <RefreshControl
                        refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                        onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
                        title="Pull to refresh" tintColor="#fff" titleColor="#fff" colors={["#FEC200"]}
                    />
                }
                />
        </View>
      );
```

And the first fetch is called on componentDidMount()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) -> it's best element for infinite lists. ( It also has  different mechanism for `onEndReachedThreshold` )

Comment: It works, I didn't get this difference between the two onEndReachedThreshold. Thank you for your help!